# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Yoga 900S

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, nvme

The problem is that Ubuntu doesn't detect the NVM SSD (Samsung 950 PRO). I have also tried Arch and all BIOS options (there aren't much) without any change.

Has someone a hint?

Comment: Is this issue present with all distributions or just Ubuntu?

Comment: I haven't found any distribution that works.

Answer (score 1):

The Yoga 710S, 900, 900S machines do NOT support running Linux out of the box. They were optimised for Windows. The reason your Linux installer cannot see the drive is that the factory BIOS is configured to use a RAID interface to talk to the disk, which is not supported by Linux (or the installer at least).

Fortunately, though, Lenovo have released a separate BIOS, which does support Linux by letting users choose AHCI as the interface controller.

For further details, [see this thread on the Lenovo Forums.](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/Yoga-900-and-Ideapad-710S-Linux-Only-BIOS/ta-p/3466850)